# DragDrop-Support of PictureBox-Control

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, controls

After some searching i figured out how dragdrop is implemented for a picturebox. But there is one thing -  the (inherited of course) allowdrop property isn't accessible from code or property window of picturebox class. So to make it work i added following line to my form-load:

`((Control)pictureBox1).AllowDrop = true;`

Why do i have to do that? In msdn it says: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

Any explanation appreciated and sorry for my grammar ;)

Comment: You should name your PictureBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PictureBox` class overrides the property and adds

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

This prevents it from being shown in IntelliSense.
However, you can still set the property without casting.

Microsoft does this when a property doesn't apply to a control. (eg, `PictureBox.Text`)
I don't know why AllowDrop wouldn't apply to a PictureBox; the source doesn't mention anything.

Comment: so i guess this is one of microsofts secrets... thanks for your quick response! if anyone has a clue, feel free to post ;)