# Where is the DragAllow property in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, drag-and-drop

I read in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DragDropImage.aspx?fid=370651&df=90&mpp=50&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Expanded) about DragAllow property of controls in C#. But I cannot found this property in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm trying to enable Drag and Drop for Picture Control. Does somebody here know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of Visual Studio 2005, the `DragAllow` property was renamed to `AllowDrop`.**

See the [relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop.aspx) on MSDN. The article you read must either be an old one, or written with an older version of Visual Studio in mind.

However, you should also note that the `AllowDrop` property is hidden for the `PictureBox` control. The function signature has the `BrowsableAttribute` set to False. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.allowdrop.aspx):

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Why this choice was made is [anyone's guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519728/dragdrop-support-of-picturebox-control), but you can still set it manually in your source code (albeit without the benefit of IntelliSense).